# How do I list all websocket connections? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, web, websocket

How do I list all running websocket connections, and if possible intercept the messages being sent and received? I am looking for a way to do this with javascript through the console so please dont answer/comment with chrome dev tools.

Comment: Chrome dev tools ws filter